# How to get values from two tables in relationship thru one column in one table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a relationship between 2 simple tables as follow:

```
Table USERS:
ID  Name
100 User1
243 User2
681 User3

Table MSGS:
FromU ToUser Txt [... DTime]
243   100    Bla bla bla
100   243    Taaa
243   681    Bo bo bo
681   243    Mi mi miiii
681   100    Exemples
100   681    Very good

Relationship:
FromU -> ID (table USERS)
ToUser -> ID (table USERS)
```

How I can get ALL messages one user send to an other one AND the answers that user get back from other users AND user's NAMES, I wander.
For exemple, if I want to get all messages User2 send to AND messages User2 get back, then I need this data:

```
FromU  Name    ToUser  Name   Txt
243    User2   100     User1  Bla bla bla
100    User1   243     User2  Taaa ...
243    User2   681     User3  Bo bo bo
681    User3   243     User2  Mi mi miiii
```

I can't get the user's names. With this SQL

```
SELECT FromU, ToUser, Txt 
FROM msgs 
WHERE FromU = 243 OR ToUser = 243 
ORDER BY DTime ASC
```

I get:

```
243   100    Bla bla bla
100   243    Taaa ...
243   681    Bo bo bo
681   243    Mi mi miiii
```

Any idea? I use MariaDB. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a join with user  (in the sample there are two joi for obtain both the name  )

```
  "SELECT m.FromU, m.ToUser, m.Txt, u1.Name as from_name, u2.name as to_name 
   FROM msgs m
   INNER JOIN user u1 on m.FromU = u1.id
   INNER JOIN user u2 on m.ToU = u2.id
   WHERE m.FromU = 243 OR m.ToUser = 243 
   ORDER BY m.DTime ASC"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of! It's what I'm looking for. Thank You again!. How I can mark your answer as right, scaisEdge?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used MariaDB but in TSSQL you would do something like:

```
SELECT from.Name as FromUser, to.Name, Txt FROM MSGS INNER JOIN USERS AS from ON from.ID = FromU INNER JOIN USERS AS to ON to.ID = ToUser WHERE FromU = 243 OR ToUser =243
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You very much Emilio, but I'm working with MariaDB.